# course from iOS' CLLocation in Android

Tags: android, ios, location, core-location

I am implementing the Android version of an already existing app written in iOS. What I have to do is log the information from various sensors. One information that I need is the course of the device, given in iOS by the course property from the CLLocation object [1].

What I am currently doing is getting the getBearing() from the Location object in Android. But I don't know if this is the correct approach or if it gives me the same value [I don't have how to test the app on iOS - I don't have an iPhone, nor a Mac]. Should I compute it in some other way, for example, by computing azimuth using the rotation matrix from Android or something else?

Thanks!

[1] https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocation/1423832-course?language=objc

Answer (score 2):

`Course` in iOS and `Bearing` in Android, both have same purpose.